# What can cause a document.ready function to be null?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have the following script in usage:

```
script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('li:last-child').hover(function () {
        $('#test').addClass('transparent'); //mouseover
    }, function () {
        $('#test').removeClass('transparent'); //mouseout
    });
});
</script>
```

With the following HTML layout:

```
<body onload="javascript that makes the menu...">
    <div id="menu" //this houses the li elements that are created by the javascript></div>
    <div id="test">
```

Essentially, I have javascript that creates a menu filled with li elements. The last of these elements should be able to change the opacity of a div with the id test on hover. The css that is relevant is as follows:

```
.transparent{
        opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

But for some reason, this code doesn't work. Inspecting in the browser's console gives me a TypeError that $(...) is null at the line that starts the javascript seen above. What could cause this error, and how could I work around it?

Comment: Sounds like `$` does not refer to jQuery.

Comment: Lol @ nickname :-) what js libraries are loaded ?

Comment: Well, you're not closing the doc ready function there. I'm not sure that's the main issue, but that's an issue.

Comment: @Chad Checking in Notepad++, the last close ) should end the doc ready function right?

Comment: @javascriptwillbetheendofme nope, it's missing a whole `});`. The last paren closes the hover callback.

Comment: @sodawillow err, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. Sorry if this is a blatantly stupid thing to not understand, I'm very new to this. Here's a fiddle that may help. I couldn't separate the script from the html section though, jsfiddle has refused to update for the past 2 days when I try and move it over.

http://jsfiddle.net/52apupu3/4/

Comment: @Chad oh, that's a typo here. It has both of them in my code. Updated to better reflect what is actually there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your JQuery library is not being loaded or it is in conflict. Have you tried to use jQuery(document) instead of $(document)? Does it have the same behavior? If it has, I'd suggest you to look the path of your library, if it is correct.

Comment: That's more of a comment than an answer. Don't use the answer section for comments.

Comment: This is the answer worked for me. No where in docs mentioned that Jquery works if $ not. Thanks. Saved my minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like jQuery is not being loaded in time. To fix this, make sure you are loading jQuery before your script runs. Also, make sure that there are no javascript errors that happen BEFORE the error you describe. (You can check this by pressing F12 in most browsers to bring up the javascript console.)

So your code might look something like this:

```
<!-- Load jQuery -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Now do stuff with jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       ...
    });
</script>
```

Note: alternatively, something could be re-defining `$`. I think this is very unlikely, but it is possible that you have some code somewhere that is doing this.

Comment: No other javascript errors at all on the page. I don't see anything that could redefine $ either. 

As for the jQuery not being loaded in time, how could I force it to load before the script runs? Does document.ready not automatically wait for this to occur?

I do have a fiddle here. I was unable to separate the script from the html portion - jsfiddle would not update properly. http://jsfiddle.net/52apupu3/4/

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your fiddle as it doesn't seem to contain the code from your question (although maybe I just missed it). Anyways, in the fiddle you are defining `$=function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }`. It also looks like you are not loading jQuery at all.

Comment: OK, I went back over it, and realized a whole bunch of things were missing. Alright, here's a new jsfiddle, and this time, I promise everything is in there. 

http://jsfiddle.net/vdum3uv7/

I made the fix regarding redefining $, and swapped it out for a new letter, "K". Still, no change in the functionality.

EDIT: Scratch that, there is a change in functionality. The Searchbar on the right doesn't seem to accept the "!w/g/i/etc" anymore after changing the variable $ to K. Now I'm even more confuzzled by this.